# Using ListView to delete SQLite row

Tags: android, android-listview

This is my current adapter.

This is what i tried to convert the date.

Comment: There are a few ways to do this. (I'll start with the easiest.) What does your row layout look like?

Comment: I use `long` values to delete rows. I added the code to my first post.

Comment: I was asking about the XML layout you use in your ListView, what is this layout? (If you use ListView's multiple choice feature, this is _really_ easy!)

Comment: No, unfortunately i don't. This would block selecting ListItems. I already tried that before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I started changing your adapter to a CursorAdapter but honestly it would be the same as this SimpleCursorAdapter example (I updated it to reflect your code as best I could.):

```
public class Example extends Activity {
    SimpleCursorAdapter adapter;
    Database database;
    ListView listView;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        database = new Database(this);
        database.open();

        // See my note below for a detailed explanation of this
        Cursor cursor = database.getAllNames();
        adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_checked, 
                cursor, 
                new String[] { "name" }, // "name" is the column in your database that I describe below
                new int[] {android.R.id.text1}, 0);

        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
        listView.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);

        Button delete = (Button) findViewById(R.id.delete_button);
        delete.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                long[] checkedIds = listView.getCheckedItemIds();
                for(long id : checkedIds)
                    database.deleteName(id);

                listView.clearChoices();
                adapter.changeCursor(database.getAllNames());
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        database.close();
        super.onDestroy();
    }
}
```

Ok, all your need to make this work is a method that returns a Cursor with all of the names (I called it `getAllNames()`) in your Database class. Now I assumed your table schema looks something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE Names (
    _id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    names TEXT);
```

You can adjust accordingly. Your `Database.getAllNames()` method should use a query like this:

```
"SELECT _id, name FROM Names;"
```

Or if you want the names alphabetized:

```
"SELECT _id, name FROM Names ORDER BY name;"
```

All together it will look like:

```
public Cursor getAllNames() {
    return NameDatabase.rawQuery("SELECT _id, name FROM Names ORDER BY name;", null);
}
```

I hope that explains a few things, honestly this is the easiest way to do what you want.

---

**Adding your own row (list item) layout**

Adding your own layout is simple enough. Since you like the look of simple_list_item_checked.xml, let's copy it's layout and tweak it for your colors:

```
<CheckedTextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/text1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
    android:checkMark="?android:attr/textCheckMark"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:paddingLeft="6dip"
    android:paddingRight="6dip"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
```

All you need to add is:

```
    android:background="#ffffffff"
    android:textColor="#ff000000"
```

(Notice that since there is only one element a ViewGroup is not necessary; no LinearLayout, no RelativeLayout, etc. Also `"@android:id/text1"` is the id that we referenced in the SimpleCursorAdapter `android.R.id.text1', when you change layouts you need to change these appropriately.)

**However** if you only want to invert the colors consider using a different Theme for you entire app. Open up your Manifest and add this theme:

```
<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Light" >
```

By default Android uses Theme.Dark, simply change it to Theme.Light. Now every item has a white background and black text by default!

**Minor Adjustment to getView()**

For future reference, in your adapter's getView() you call getLayoutInflater() for every new row. You only need to get the LayoutInflater once in the constructor and save it in a variable, possibly `LayoutInflater mLayoutInflater`, and use this in getView() with `mLayoutInflater.inflate(...)`.

Hope that helps!

Comment: I'm using a CustomAdapter. I added it to my first post.

Comment: I see you are actually extending an ArrayAdapter which does not retain the SQLite ids like a CursorAdapter. (This is what you were seeing earlier.) Let's change it to extend a CursorAdapter. **Also** you used getView() and the ViewHolder() _perfectly_. (Upvote just for that.)

Comment: Heya, deleting works now and the ListView works, too. Thank you for showing me the magic of SimpleCursorAdapter. :) There's just one little problem now. The CursorAdapter uses a standard layout (android.R.layout.simple_list_item_checked) and i can't replace it with my row layout. I mean it wouldn't be a problem, because this standard looks great, too. But the color of the text seems to be (Alpha = 0), i mean it's invisible until i click on it. Then the textcolor becomes black. You have any idea how to solve this?

Comment: @user1617102 I updated my answer. I also removed most of my comments to clean up the "extended discussion".

Comment: Do you have an idea how to convert the date (milliseconds) to a formatted date String? I added the code in the first post.

Comment: Did you figure out how to use implement the Checkable interface on your custom row? It looks like you'll need a custom CursorAdapter to convert the date, easy enough. But would you ask this is a new question, since this beyond your original question? (Use an @Sam comment when you post the new question, I'm happy to answer it!)

Comment: Ok, i will create a new question for the conversion. In fact the checkmark currently doesn't show up, but the items are selected (i know this because i can delete them after clicking on them). Is the Checkable interface done programmatically or in XML?

Comment: The time conversion question has been solved. The only problem that remains is the checkmark that's not showing up.

Comment: Awesome! The checkable layout answer is a long block or two of code. Would you write a new question for this?

Comment: Ok, i write @Sam in the first comment.

Comment: Oh, you need write a comment for me here otherwise I won't get notified. (I just found your other question... Glad Erik gave you a great answer.)

Comment: Question is posted. Can you find it?